# How to extract more than 900,000 bytes using SharpZipLib BZip2

Tags: c#, bzip2, sharpziplib

When using `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib` to decompress BZip2 files I am having an issue where only the first 900,000 uncompressed bytes are extracted. I've tried both the `BZip2InputStream` and the `BZip2.Decompress` static method to no avail. The compressed data is 8,518 bytes which I have confirmed is the length of the byte array that I pass in as `compressedDataByteArray`, and the decompressed data should be 1,134,592 bytes - so I can see that it is being truncated.

My attempt with BZip2InputStream - observe that the console writes out "900000" instead of "1134592":

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var compressedDataByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes("data.bz2");

            using (var mstream = new MemoryStream(compressedDataByteArray))
            using (var zstream = new BZip2InputStream(mstream))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(zstream))
            {
                string uncompressedData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(uncompressedData.Length);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Alternatively, I have tried the `BZip2.Decompress` method - observe that the console also writes out "900000" instead of "1134592":

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var compressedDataByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes("data.bz2");

            using (var indata = new MemoryStream(compressedDataByteArray))
            using (var outdata = new MemoryStream())
            {
                BZip2.Decompress(indata, outdata, false);
                string uncompressedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(outdata.ToArray());
                Console.WriteLine(uncompressedData.Length);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Is there some flag or option I am missing? Does the library need to be licensed? I'm not clear why the uncompressed data always stops there. For reference I am using #SharpZipLib 1.3.0 Nuget package

Here is the bz2 file I am using: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1CD0XnJjAITxIrBqD90Msnygc4xnDXk5X&export=download

Comment: `string uncompressedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(outdata.ToArray());` <-- This is very inefficient btw.

Comment: Why are you representing _binary content_ as a `String`?

Comment: Please provide us with an example `*.bz2` file or other `compressedDataByteArray` data somewhere.

Comment: Please verify the stream is intact by getting the full bytes back from `bzip2 -d`

Comment: It's a .bz2 file of text file containing rows of JSON, hence getting it out as a string. @dai  The file is definitely complete as I am able to unzip it in Windows shell, and in 7-zip. I am uploading the file using FileUpload control.

Comment: @PatrickJones The Windows Shell doesn't support BZip2 files... so what **exactly** are you referring to? Also, BZip2 is like GZip: it compresses a single file: it isn't a container or archive format like `.zip` or `.7z`.

Comment: I meant Windows explorer. I am aware that it is like gzip and contains a single file - as stated in the question, the problem is that using SharpZipLib to decompress it, I am only getting the first 900,000 bytes of uncompressed data when the uncompressed data exceeds that size.

Comment: Why are your using Encoding.UTF8.GetString(() which will corrupt the data?  The bytes 0x80 get changed when UTF8 is used.  There should be no reason to use Encoding.

Comment: @jdweng - I don't exactly know what I'm doing, which is why I'm asking here. The uncompressed data will be a normal ascii string - so can you provide guidance on the best way instead of just saying it's bad?

Comment: I appreciate it friends, but can we stick to the actual question about the 900,000 byte limit and not get caught up on other things? the 900,001st character happens to be a quote sign `"` which I think has less to do with how the stream is read and more to do with the library and what BZip2 calls blocks. I need to solve the issue with getting all of the uncompressed data and then can move on to resolving inefficient code.

Comment: You said in title 900,00 bytes.  Is it bytes or string?  You have to restore data to same type before it was compressed.  When you compress you should never convert a byte array to a string.  It should stay as bytes unless you use an algorithm (like zip) that handles bytes conversion to string properly.  Encode does not properly handle the byte to string conversion properly.  Encode changes the data.  Even UTF8 makes changes.

Comment: @PatrickJones None of us can help you until you share a link to the `*.bz2` file you're trying to read.

Comment: Hi @Dai, sorry for the delay, I needed to make sure I can share, here it is: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1CD0XnJjAITxIrBqD90Msnygc4xnDXk5X&export=download

Comment: "and the decompressed data should be 1,134,592 bytes - so I can see that it is being truncated" - no you can't. You can see that the resulting string has 900,000 *characters*, but that doesn't say anything about how many *bytes* are in the decompressed data. (Well, it says that it has at least that many bytes.) **Get rid of the string conversion.** Just log `outdata.Length`...

Comment: Having just tried that myself with the file you've provided, it's still showing 900,000, so the string conversion isn't the problem, but as evidenced by all the comments, the string conversion part is distracting, and your question would be much clearer without it.

Comment: Bzip2 is compressed in blocks, the default block size being 900,000 bytes. Bzip2 support in SharpZipLib seems to have some issues, seeing the open issues and pull requests, but I don't know whether any of those are relevant to this issue. Can you try another library?

Comment: Thanks guys, I will investigate some other libraries now and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently, it may be a shortcoming with the SharpZipLib, so I migrated to SharpCompress and it now works as expected:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var compressedDataByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes("data.bz2");

    using (var mstream = new MemoryStream(compressedDataByteArray))
    using (var unzipstream = new BZip2Stream(mstream, SharpCompress.Compressors.CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(unzipstream))
    {
        string uncompressedData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(uncompressedData.Length);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Much thanks to @CodeCaster.